# Why does vagrant up not generate a code directory?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Currently trying to set up a laravel project I cloned using vagrant on Windows 10. This is my Homestead.yaml file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.sshhstead/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.sshhstead/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\nikulas\Homestead\code\api
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: false
    - mariadb: true
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

#services:
#    - enabled:
#        - "postgresql@12-main"
#    - disabled:
#        - "postgresql@11-main"

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Inside of my homestead folder I have a code folder that contains my project. Currently it is not being mapped to my vagrant environment and when I ssh into it after running vagrant up and ls I get nothing back.

This is what I get in the terminal when I run vagrant up.

```
PS C:\Users\nikulas\Homestead> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '11.0.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
    homestead: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead: Booting VM...
==> homestead: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    homestead: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead: SSH auth method: private key
==> homestead: Machine booted and ready!
==> homestead: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> homestead: Setting hostname...
==> homestead: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> homestead: Mounting shared folders...
    homestead: /vagrant => C:/Users/nikulas/Homestead
==> homestead: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> homestead: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but I've had a much better experience working with Valet, bit of a pain to get working on windows but it's much more lightweight https://medium.com/@samimrezgui123/how-to-install-laravel-valet-on-windows-os-afdc23d69719 this kind of stuff is what drove me away from Homestead

Comment: Did you add the mapping after creating the VM? You can rerun the provisioning with `vagrant provision` as it says in the output.

Comment: @CalumHalpin not sure but I have run vagrant provision and then vagrant up and it does not help.

Comment: @nikulasoskarsson, you say you ran `vagrant provision` and then `vagrant up` but you need to run `vagrant provision` when the VM is already running. Is that what you did?